# What does this mean in php.ini?

Tags: php, assert

```
assert.active = On

assert.bail = Off
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 6):

If `assert.active=on` you can call `assert('$x==1')` in your code. If it fails (i.e. $x is something else than 1), depending on the value of assert.bail your script will either terminate or you get a warning. See more in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php

Answer (score 3):

From the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.assert.active):

> assert.active: Enable assert()
>   evaluation.
>   assert.bail :
>   Terminate script execution on failed
>   assertions.

Answer (score 1):

You can always find it from php user manual

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

assert.active boolean

Enable assert() evaluation.

assert.bail boolean

Terminate script execution on failed assertions.